# How to convert rows to columns with multiple rows and nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I hope you can help me on this one: 
I want to create a query in order to have the records of a table as columns but this columns can have multiple rows.

Example:

```
| Id | Value  | ColumnName    |
| 1  | A      | Q1            |
| 2  | B      | Q2            |
| 3  | C      | Q2            |
| 4  | D      | Q2            |
| 5  | E      | Q3            |
| 6  | F      | Q3            |
```

This is what I want:

```
| Q1   | Q2   | Q3
| A    | B    | E 
| NULL | C    | F    
| NULL | D    | NULL
```

How can I get this result in one single query? (I really need to have this in a query because I need to create a view for this)

Thanks and regards!

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on? 2012? 2016?

Comment: The version is 2014

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation with `row_number()`:

```
select max(case when columnname = 'Q1' then value end) as q1,
       max(case when columnname = 'Q2' then value end) as q2,
       max(case when columnname = 'Q3' then value end) as q3       
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by columnname order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by seqnum;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using pivot

```
select pv.* from 
tablename
pivot
(max(Value) for columnname in ([Q1],[Q2],[Q3])) as pv
```